# How to return the latest rows per group in pyspark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a stream which I read in pyspark using `spark.readStream.format('delta')`. The data consists of multiple columns including a `type`, `date` and `value` column.

Example DataFrame;

| type | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-21 | 6 |
| 1 | 2020-01-16 | 5 |
| 2 | 2020-01-20 | 8 |
| 2 | 2020-01-15 | 4 |

I would like to create a DataFrame that keeps track of the latest `state` per type. One of the most easy methods to do when working on static (batch) data is to use windows, but using windows on non-timestamp columns is not supported. Another option would look like

```
stream.groupby('type').agg(last('date'), last('value')).writeStream
```

but I think Spark cannot guarantee the ordering here, and using `orderBy` is also not supported in structured streaming before the aggrations.

Do you have any suggestions on how to approach this challenge?

Answer (score 0):

simple use the to_timestamp() function that can be import by `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`
on the date column so that you use the window function.
e.g

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df=spark.createDataFrame(
        data = [ ("1","2020-01-21")],
        schema=["id","input_timestamp"])
df.printSchema()

+---+---------------+-------------------+
|id |input_timestamp|timestamp          |
+---+---------------+-------------------+
|1  |2020-01-21     |2020-01-21 00:00:00|
+---+---------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

"but using windows on non-timestamp columns is not supported"
are you saying this from stream point of view, because same i am able to do.

Here is the solution to your problem.

```
windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("type").orderBy("date")
df1=df.withColumn("rank",rank().over(windowSpec))
df1.show()

+----+----------+-----+----+
|type|      date|value|rank|
+----+----------+-----+----+
|   1|2020-01-16|    5|   1|
|   1|2020-01-21|    6|   2|
|   2|2020-01-15|    4|   1|
|   2|2020-01-20|    8|   2|
+----+----------+-----+----+

w = Window.partitionBy('type')
df1.withColumn('maxB', F.max('rank').over(w)).where(F.col('rank') == F.col('maxB')).drop('maxB').show()

+----+----------+-----+----+
|type|      date|value|rank|
+----+----------+-----+----+
|   1|2020-01-21|    6|   2|
|   2|2020-01-20|    8|   2|
+----+----------+-----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using pyspark window function and max date by partition.

Streaming process might reject the aggregation. Try applying the above using for each batch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).